# Scrolling for element that has flex-grow

Tags: css

I have 2 columns, a fixed width column on the left and a column on right the fills the remainder of the screen,  I added an element `inner-scroll` in the right column  with `overflow scroll` but the scroll doesn't display, the parent column is just expanded which creates a scroll for the entire window.

I can't add overflow: scroll to the right-column class because I don't want the top bar above the `inner scroll` element to be inside the scroll, I could fix position it to the top of the inner element but I'd rather get it working by having the inner element show a scroll.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex

How can I get the inner element to scroll?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.right-column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.inner-top-bar {
  background: lightskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

inner-right-column {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you have given the width for the `.left-column` flex using the `flex:0 0 200px` hence it takes `200px` everytime. But u havent given the next flex a `width` at all hence it takes until the division ends and the `overflow` doesnt work. I have added the `left` and `rightcolumn`some width and then ive added the overflow and it works.
hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.right-column {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: lightgreen;
}

.inner-top-bar {
  background: lightskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="inner-top-bar">non-scroll top</div>
    <div class="inner-scroll" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the left 20% though, I want it to always be 200px

Comment: @doe i just changed css a bit try these css it worked for me

Comment: It works in the code snipped but not here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex

Comment: @doe It does work for me try copying full css and replacing it.

Comment: @doe can you update the link with the code or add minimal working example

Answer (score 0):

Because of too much content, right column fall out from viewport. You must limit `.right-column` width to display scroll. For example `width: calc(100% - 200px)`

Result

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.right-column {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: lightgreen;
}

.inner-top-bar {
  background: lightskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="inner-top-bar">non-scroll top</div>
    <div class="inner-scroll">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the scroll still doesn't show and the table is outside the right column